# What is the big plant with white flowers on the photo?

Tags: species-identification, botany

What is the 3m tall plant with white flower? It is from Central Europe and there is a creek near to it. I have a guess, but I want to know for sure...

[image: the big plant]

Is the small one the same species?

[image: small plant]

More high res photos here:

- https://ibb.co/cAaUMU
- https://ibb.co/ih4Zo9
- https://ibb.co/eJSyFp
- https://ibb.co/gstS89
- https://ibb.co/kQ2OWU

Comment: Probably Angelica sylvestris. (No time to look more closely now)

Comment: The small one looks like Ground Elder (Aegopodium podagraria)... Were the leaves serrated?

Comment: @JulPal I think so. But they looked like the big plant, which was 2.5m tall...

Comment: The photos are high res, but out of focus and motion blurred so it is really hard to identify accurately.

Answer (score -1):

They both look like poison hemlock (***Conium maculatum***).  It can grow up to 3m tall and grows in moist areas including along creekbeds. One of it's common names is European Hemlock.  It is toxic to some domestic animals and humans.

[image]

Source: [United States Department of Agriculture](https://www.ars.usda.gov/pacific-west-area/logan-ut/poisonous-plant-research/docs/poison-hemlock-conium-maculatum/)

[image]

Source: http://natureid.blogspot.com/2011/11/poison-hemlock-111211-elkhorn-slough.html

Comment: According to wiki it can grow only 2m tall. I checked other photos, the flowers are smaller and not that dense. I thought first it is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heracleum_mantegazzianum but the leaves are different. It is in the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apiaceae family and I suspect I had phototoxicity from it on my leg, but I am not sure. It might be unrelated.

Comment: The closest I could find based on the leaves is Angelica atropurpurea . No idea what it does in Europe though, it should be in America. :D

Comment: I concur, not *Conium maculatum* the overall habit is completely different.  Also, if you just took these photos and are not at particularly high altitude *C. maculatum* should have finished blooming (it has finished at least a few weeks ago in the Central US).  *C. maculatum* has a distinct mousey smell which is hard to miss, and it very toxic to the point it should not be handled with bare hands.

Comment: @inf3rno if you had touched H. mantegazzianum, you would have known, trust me. I slightly touched it with the rear of my knees and after a couple of hours I couldn't bend them without almost screaming in pain. It is not a pain you cannot be sure of.

Comment: @inf3rno: Huh, according to the USDA it can grow to 3m tall - maybe that's just in the US.  I'm glad it wasn't Giant Hogweed (H. mantegazzianum).  I've never touched it as LinuxBlanket has but we were given a flyer at work earlier this year warning us about it

Comment: @LinuxBlanket Well then I was lucky with my plant. I had only rash and now 1 week after it some small red blisters. I used sunscreen on it, I am not sure whether it was phototoxicity or my skin was red because of other kind of toxicity. I am not even sure what I touched, I started to look for toxic plants only after I had the rash and I found this. I am pretty sure it is some kind of Angelica, but there are so many species... :-)

Comment: @Linuxblanket Reaction to H. mantaggazianum varies greatly between people and depends strongly on exposure to the sun.